# Comic/manhwa about a girl/woman who is reincarnated as a concubine and later forms a combat team with other women she saved

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, reincarnation

Trying to find this comic/manhwa, I believe. I read it long time ago and am trying to find it since the author was done.

I’m very hazy on it but it starts off a girl/woman being reincarnated as a concubine for a guy. She breaks out and lands on a cart, where she meets a prince/Duke (I think) and does a fake wedding so she doesn’t have to be a concubine. She's a very strong woman that’s actually a blood demon (you find out near the end or where I stopped). All the women look up to the main character and she raises all her maids and women she saved as a combat team.

That’s pretty much what I remember. Hopefully someone knows what I’m talking about.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Also, did she have any distinctive powers, skills or weapons you can tell us about?